# Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table in Entity Framework 4.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm stuck at trying to write the Entity Framework 4.1 code first model for the following DB relationship.

Here is a visual of the relationship.[image]

dbo.[Companies] can have either Seller or Debtor as Company Types.

dbo.[SellerDebtors] defines the connection a Seller Company has with a Debtor Company.

The code i've written is based on my original EF 4.0 POCO model code. This is what I've come up with - This code does not work.

```
public class SellerDebtor
{
    public int SellerDebtorId { get; set; }
    public int DebtorCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int SellerCompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company DebtorCompany { get; set; }
    public Company SellerCompany { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SellerDebtorInfo> SellerDebtorInfos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SellerDebtorFile> SellerDebtorFiles { get; set; }    
}


public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyInfo> CompanyInfos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyFile> CompanyFiles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SellerDebtor> SellerDebtorDebtorCompanies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SellerDebtor> SellerDebtorSellerCompanies { get; set; }

}
```

At the moment, I'm getting this as an error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'DebtorCompany_CompanyId'.
Invalid column name 'SellerCompany_CompanyId'.
Invalid column name 'Company_CompanyId'.
Invalid column name 'Company_CompanyId1'.
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to maintain the naming of the relationships.

I'm guessing i need to set some attributes but i'm not sure what to set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EF is not able to determine by convention which navigation properties on your 2 classes belong together and creates 4 relationships (without an end on the other side) instead of 2 (with ends on both sides). This problem occurs always when you have more than one navigation property of the same type (`Company` in your case) in the same class. You could try to fix this the following way:

```
public class SellerDebtor
{
    public int SellerDebtorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DebtorCompany")]
    public int DebtorCompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SellerCompany")]
    public int SellerCompanyId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SellerDebtorDebtorCompanies")]
    public Company DebtorCompany { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SellerDebtorSellerCompanies")]
    public Company SellerCompany { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SellerDebtorInfo> SellerDebtorInfos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SellerDebtorFile> SellerDebtorFiles { get; set; }    
}
```

`[InverseProperty(...)]` defines the navigation property on the other end of the relationship and it tells EF explicitely which pairs of navigation properties belong together in a relationship.

Answer (score 3):

This blog has the example using Fluent API configurations.

[Multiple foreign keys within same table using CodeFirst Entity Framework and Fluent API](http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2013/06/multiple-foreign-keys-with-same-table.html)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasOptional(b => b.PrimaryContact)         
            .WithMany(a => a.PrimaryContactFor).HasForeignKey(b=>b.PrimaryContactID);
```

Comment: Really glad you posted this. I needed this Fluent API example today.

Comment: IMHO the best answer. The fluent API is as clear as a sunny day.