# EF 4.1 Code First Relationship table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Setup**

Using MVC 3 + Code First

**Here are my classes**

```
public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        public String Sex { get; set; }

        public String Password { get; set; }

        public String PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastOnline { get; set; }

        public String SecurityQuestion { get; set; }

        public String SecurityAnswer { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FamilyMember> Families { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }


    }


public class Relationship
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Member1")]
        public Guid Member1ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Member2")]
        public Guid Member2ID { get; set; }

        public Guid RelationshipTypeID { get; set; }

        public virtual RelationshipType RelationshipType { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member1 { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member2 { get; set; }

    }
```

**Here is the problem**

The database table "Relationship" is being created with the following columns:

ID, Member1ID, Member2ID, RelationshipTypeID, **Member_ID**

Why is it creating the **Member_ID** column?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015964/multiple-foreign-keys-pointing-to-same-table-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first) post in which the user has the same type of setup, but I am unsure of how to define the InverseProperty correctly. I tried using fluent API calls but from what I can tell they will not work here since I have two foreign keys referring to the same table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Member_ID` is the foreign key column which EF created for the navigation property `Member.Relationships`. It belongs to a third association from `Member.Relationships` refering to an end endpoint which is not exposed in your `Relationship` entity. This relationship has nothing to do with the other two relationships from `Relationship.Member1` and `Relationship.Member2` which also both have an endpoint not exposed in `Member`.

I guess, this is not what you want. You need always *pairs* of endpoints in two entities to create an association. One endpoint is always a navigation property. The second endpoint *can* also be a navigation property but it is not required, you can omit the second navigation property.

Now, what is not possible, is to associate *two* navigation properties (`Member1` and `Member2`) in one entity with *one* navigation property (`Relationships`) in the other entity. That is what you are trying to do apparently.

I assume that your `Member.Relationships` property is supposed to express that the member is either `Member1` or `Member2` in the relationship, or that it *participates* in the relationship, *no matter* if as `Member1` or `Member2`.

Unfortunately you cannot express this in the model appropriately. You have to introduce something like `RelationsshipsAsMember1` and `RelationsshipsAsMember2` and for these two collection you can use the `InverseProperty` attribute as shown in the other question. In addition you can add a helper property which concats the two collections. But this is not a mapped property but readonly:

```
public class Member
{
    // ...

    [InverseProperty("Member1")]
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> RelationshipsAsMember1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Member2")]
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> RelationshipsAsMember2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Relationship> AllRelationships
    {
        get { return RelationshipsAsMember1.Concat(RelationshipsAsMember2); }
    }
}
```

Accessing `AllRelationships` will cause two queries and roundtrips to the database (with lazy loading) to load both collections first before they get concatenated in memory.

With this mapping the `Member_ID` column will disappear and you will only get the two expected foreign key columns `Member1ID`, `Member2ID` because now you have only two associations and not three anymore.

You could also think about if you need the `Relationships` collection in the `Member` entity at all. As said, navigation properties on both sides are not required. If you rarely need to navigate from a member to its relationships you could fetch the relationships also with queries on the `Relationship` set, like so:

```
var relationships = context.Relationships
    .Where(r => r.Member1ID == givenMemberID || r.Member2ID == givenMemberID)
    .ToList();
```

...or...

```
var relationships = context.Relationships
        .Where(r => r.Member1ID == givenMemberID)
    .Concat(context.Relationships
        .Where(r => r.Member2ID == givenMemberID)
    .ToList();
```

This would give you all relationships the member with ID = `givenMemberID` participates in without the need of a navigation collection on the `Member` entity.

Comment: You made me think about it more, and I think you are right about not even needing the Member.Relationships property. I guess from my past works normally you always have a way to navigate. But if I need to load relationships, I can just query the Relationship table. One disadvantage to this is that it would not be available easily in my View Model.