# Entity Framework Code First with one class having two references to another

Tags: ef-code-first

I love EF Code First, but sometimes it seems it would be easier to just define the tables in SQL.

In this case I have two models, something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookRecommendation> BookRecommendations { get; set; }
    // additional properties about the item
}

public class BookRecommendation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // public int BookId { get; set; } // from attempts to use data annotations
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    // public int BookRecommendedId { get; set; } // from attempts to use data annotations
    public virtual Book BookRecommended { get; set; }
    // additional properties about the relationship between the two items
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work correctly with either data annotations or the fluent API.

There are questions like [Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table in Entity Framework 4.1 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6015964/11912), [Entity Framework 4.1 InverseProperty Attribute and ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5828394/11912), and others like this, but these tend to involve collections on both end.

My models could just be wrong, since frustration set in early and I thought about how I'd do this in SQL:

```
Book
    Id
    Name
    // other properties

Recommendation
    Id
    BookId
    RecommendedBookId
    // other properties
```

There would then be foreign keys between `Book.Id : Recommendation.BookId` and `Book.Id : Recommendation.RecommendedBookId`.

What do I need to do via data annotations or fluent API to get this working, or how should I modify my models?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table)

Comment: Honestly, given that this question is over 4 years old, I can't say 100% whether it's a possible duplicate of that or not. But based upon the two highest rated answers on that question, and the last answer to this one from March '13, and that I seemingly wasn't getting an exception, but possibly tables that didn't match my database-first assumptions, I'd lean toward these being different.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. See 

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookRecommendation> BookRecommendations { get; set; }

}

public class BookRecommendation
{
    public int BookRecommendationID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; } 
    public string remarks { get; set; } //Some recommendation text

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

}
```

I guess this should solve the problem! It will make a Book entity and a collection of Recommendations for it. Which means a book can have many recommendations and a recommendation will belong to only one book. When a book is created and then you try to write recommendation for it, you will see that there's a dropdown box that has the name of the book through its "BookID".

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Sorry it took me a year to find this.

You need to tell EF which of your 2 relationships back to Book is the one that BookRecommendation is pointing to using the [InversePropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute.aspx). In code:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("BookRecommended")]
    public virtual ICollection<BookRecommendation> BookRecommendations { get; set; }
    // additional properties about the item
}

public class BookRecommendation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookRecommended")]
    public int BookRecommendedId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book BookRecommended { get; set; }
}
```

So the InverseProperty on Book names the BookRecommended property on BookRecommendation so EF is clear on which of the 2 FKs this one refers to. For good measure the 2 ForeignKey attributes just make it possible to explicitly name the FK properties on BookRecommendation - you can get rid of the extra properties if you want, but the attribute has to be there if you keep them.