# Entity Framework 5 (pre-release) newbie issue about entity relations, etc

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table) SO question.

I want to do something similar in EF 5. I don't see the ForeignKey attribute but instead an Association attribute in EF5.

Also, can someone explain what this does/means :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.HomeTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.GuestTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.AwayMatches)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.GuestTeamId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

This is the explanation :

> Primary keys are mapped by default convention. Team must have two
>   collection of matches. You can't have single collection referenced by
>   two FKs. Match is mapped without cascading delete because it doesn't
>   work in these self referencing many-to-many.

What I want to do is very similar to the example in the link but I don't know :

1. When I need to modify DbContext
2. When the primary keys will link to each other
3. When I need to explicitly use Association to create the relationship

Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so... I can't answer the ForeignKey attribute question on EF beta for I haven't had the chance to check it out yet.

However...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Match>() - Take the entity "Match" and perform following operations on it
.HasRequired(m => m.HomeTeam) - The entity needs to have a non-null navigation HomeTeam...
.WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches) - ... which has a subset of Matches by navigation HomeMatches
.HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId) ... and the associating foreign key is HomeTeamId on Match
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false); ... and don't cascade when the entity is deleted.
```

That's the beauty of LINQ, it's more often than not self-documenting.

Now, as for your three questions...

1. Only modify DbContext when you are changing your model relations or adding/deleting an entity. If you're adding, you need to do a 
   public DbSet Entities { get; set; 
   And remove it if deleting, etc.
2. Primary keys don't link to each other. Foreign Keys link to Primary Keys. By convention, if you have a ProjectId, a navigation object called Project and another entity called Project with a property called Id, it will automatically map ProjectId from the first entity to the Id of Project entity and give the Project entity as a navigation item to first entity when you fetch data from the DB via EF:
3. Only if you need non-convention based relationships. Ie, your primary keys are along the lines of "tblId" or "ParentId" instead of "Id" and "ProjectId", for example. Or you need a different kind of behaviour on some items, such as cascading on deletion for only select entities.

Answer (score 1):

In EF 5, if you're using Migrations, you can alter the migration code to not implement the cascade delete:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Match",
            c => new
                {
                    MatchId = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    HomeTeamId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                 })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.MatchId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Team", t => t.HomeTeamId, cascadeDelete: false)                
            .Index(t => t.MatchId)
            .Index(t => t.HomeTeamId);

    }
```

Or something like that.