# Code-first Entity Framework - Multiple Foreign Keys For the Same Table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a `Holiday` table and a `User` table.

The `Holiday` table has columns `RequesterID` and `AuthorisedByID`, which both link to the primary key of the `User` table.

This is my `Holiday` model:

```
public class Holiday
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid HolidayId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public Guid RequesterId { get; set; }

    public Guid? AuthorisedById { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to declare the `AuthorisedByID` as a foreign key in the User table just like I think I did with `RequesterId` column.

I wonder if you can give me some hints on how to resolve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code first is not able to match up the properties in the two classes on its own.

To fix these problems, you can use the InverseProperty annotation to specify the    alignment of the properties.

```
[ForeignKey("RequesterUser")]
public Guid RequesterId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AuthorisedUser")]
public Guid AuthorisedById { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("RequesterHoliday")]
public virtual User RequesterUser{ get; set; }

[InverseProperty("AuthorisedHoliday")]
public virtual User AuthorisedUser{ get; set; }

public List<Holiday> RequesterHoliday { get; set; }
public List<Holiday> AuthorisedHoliday{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This really needs to be cleaned up. Pluralize the collection names, etc. Is this supposed to be two separate tables? Because that isn't clear.