# The relationship '{0}' was not loaded because the type '{1}' is not available

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm getting: `The relationship 'Echipieri.Data.Event_Hosts' was not loaded because the type 'Echipieri.Data.User' is not available.`

I have found a few post about this problem but didn't find a solution for me.

Here are my entities:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AboutSelf { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        //relational properties        
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Reputation> Reputation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Hobbies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Reputation = new HashSet<Reputation>();
            Hobbies = new HashSet<Category>();
            Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
            Events = new HashSet<Event>();
            Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        }
    }

public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    //relational properties
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Hosts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Going { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {
        Hosts = new HashSet<User>();
        Going = new HashSet<User>();
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
}
```

And the mapping (Fluent API):

```
public UserMap()
{
    Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.Password).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.FirstName).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.LastName).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.AboutSelf).IsOptional();
    Property(x => x.BirthDate).IsRequired();

    //relational properties
    HasRequired(x => x.Location).WithMany(x => x.Users).HasForeignKey(x => x.LocationID);

    HasMany(x => x.Reputation).WithRequired(x => x.User).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);
    HasMany(x => x.Hobbies).WithMany(x => x.Subscribers)
                            .Map(x => 
                            {
                                x.ToTable("User_Category");
                                x.MapLeftKey("User");
                                x.MapRightKey("Category");
                            });
    HasMany(x => x.Groups).WithMany(x => x.Members)
                            .Map(x =>
                            {
                                x.ToTable("User_Group");
                                x.MapLeftKey("User");
                                x.MapRightKey("Group");
                            });
    HasMany(x => x.Events).WithMany(x => x.Going)
                            .Map(x => 
                            {
                                x.ToTable("User_Events");
                                x.MapLeftKey("User");
                                x.MapRightKey("Event");
                            });
    HasMany(x => x.Posts).WithRequired(x => x.Author).HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorID);
}

public EventMap()
{
    Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.StartDate).IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.EndDate).IsRequired();

    //relational properties
    HasRequired(x => x.Location).WithMany(x => x.Events).HasForeignKey(x => x.LocationID);
    HasRequired(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Events).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryID);

    HasMany(x => x.Hosts).WithMany(x => x.Events)
                            .Map(x =>
                            {
                                x.ToTable("Event_Hosts");
                                x.MapLeftKey("Event");
                                x.MapRightKey("Host");
                            });
    HasMany(x => x.Going).WithMany(x => x.Events)
                            .Map(x =>
                            {
                                x.ToTable("User_Events");
                                x.MapLeftKey("User");
                                x.MapRightKey("Event");
                            });
    HasMany(x => x.Posts);
}
```

From what I researched (but couldn't find a concrete answer) the problem is that `Hosts` and `Going` are of the same type(`User`) can someone tell me if this is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the root of the error you're getting, but if you look in `EventMap` (which I'm assuming is the constructor for some `EntityTypeConfiguration`):

> ```
> HasMany(x => x.Hosts).WithMany(x => x.Events)
>                      .Map(x =>
>                      {
>                          x.ToTable("Event_Hosts");
>                          x.MapLeftKey("Event");
>                          x.MapRightKey("Host");
>                      });
> HasMany(x => x.Going).WithMany(x => x.Events)
>                      .Map(x =>
>                      {
>                          x.ToTable("User_Events");
>                          x.MapLeftKey("User");
>                          x.MapRightKey("Event");
>                      });
> ```

In this section, you're mapping two different relationships to the same `User.Events` property. This is a problem, for example, when you add an item to `User.Events` -- would that added `Event` have a new user in `Hosts` or `Going`?

You'll need to have a separate property for each relationship. For example, add this to `User`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Event> HostedEvents { get; set; }
```

and your hosts relationship can be

```
HasMany(x => x.Hosts).WithMany(x => x.HostedEvents)
```

*Source: [Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship was not loaded because the type is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610063/schema-specified-is-not-valid-errors-the-relationship-was-not-loaded-because-t)*

---

If you want `User.Events` to automatically include both hosted events and events that the user is going to, then the navigational mappings can't use that property, and the property would need to return a query of some sort.

Comment: `HostedEvents` is actually what I ended up doing and relized it made no sense to use `Events` as a propert for both the going events and the hosted ones.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is because of table name conflict.

I have another edmx model that has some tables with similar names. Just click on the table in the designer, then in the properties change the name to something different!

Comment: I just wanted to add this was the solution for my issue - i had two models referencing the same table.  Very difficult and cryptic thing to figure out.  Best practice should be to add the model name to the table I think (like mePerson for Person table)