# Create one to many association without foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, one-to-many

Giving the following tables.

```
Project
Id: int not null PK
Type: nvarchar(10) not null 
SomeProperty: nvarchar(50)

ChangeRequest
Id: int not null PK
Type: nvarchar(10) not nul
SomeProperty: nvarchar(50)

Approval
Id: int not null PK
RowId: int not null
RowType: nvarchar(10) not null
SomeProperty: nvarchar(50)
```

I want to have associations like this:

- Project(Id, Type) -> Approval(RowId, RowType)
- ChangeRequest(Id, Type) -> Approval(RowId, RowType)

In a way that if I was selecting the data from database I would do something like:

```
select p*, a.*
from Project p
left join Approval a on a.RowId = p.Id and a.RowType = p.Type
```

Project and ChangeRequest are entities completely different (I just put the simplified model), but both may have 0..N Approvals.

Is it possible to map such relations using Entity Framework?

Comment: Are you asking how to add constraints to the ERD on the database, or are you asking how to SELECT related records from tables with C#?

Comment: Do you think you can use Inheritance? Create a Base class called Master, and then inherit Master1 and Master2 from the base class. It would be great if you can give details about Master1 and Master2 classes?

Comment: You might want to rethink your table design. With your current design, how would you know if an entry in the Detail table should link to Master1 or Master2?

Comment: how do you have a relationship *without* a Foreign Key? the FK is what defines the relationship.....

Comment: Similar to your case for code first in EF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table