# Multiple navigation properties ASP.NET MVC Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, code-first, navigation-properties

I always have problems with relations beetween classes in code first when there is several relations beetweens classes.

I have a User class and a Review class. A user that can send messages have a list of reviews. A review have a sender and a receiver.

```
 public class Review
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdReceiver { get; set; }
    public int IdSender { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdSender")]
    public virtual User Sender{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReceiver")]
    public virtual User Receiver{ get; set; }
}

 public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to get the list of the reviews of a user with a user object. (Why I put the review list in the User class). With a review, I need to have access to the sender and the receiver.

I need to make relations beetween these tables but when I try, I have too many relations.

Do I need something to make several navigation properties beetween 2 classes and how to create there relations in a good way?

Also, I have often delete on cascade errors. I heard about fluent API but not really.

Comment: A similar question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table

Comment: There is no such thing as ASP.NET MVC code first.

Comment: You don't know the difference beetween code first and db first?

Comment: @skofman In the other example in the solution, they put 2 list in the team class (Home and Away). But for my case, I don't really have 2 types of review :/ Do I need to split my list anyway?

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe  Brendan is trying to tell you that it is actually called "Entity Framework code first".

Comment: Thanks Brandan. But someone knows a solution to my problem?