# Unique values for two foreign keys in same table

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Frame Core Code First with an ASP MVC project I'm working on.

I have a table with two foreign keys that reference the same table. I followed this great example: [Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table)

How can I enforce it so that the value combinations can only exist once?

i.e.

```
Id   Value1    Value
1    1         2        --This is ok
2    1         3        --This is ok
3    1         2        --This is bad. Duplicate combination
4    3         1        --This is bad. This is just the reverse of Id 2
```

Thank you.

Comment: The duplicate `1,2` can be covered by a unique index (`.HasIndex()`), preventing reverse references can only be enforced by validations.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, your direction helped me find a solution to this. https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/indexes.html I will need to do more research concerning validation to prevent the reverse from happening.