# having 2 one to one relations EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been doing some research into the fluent API to be able to make this but i am not sure if that is the way to go, from what i understand the `OnModelCreate` will recreate a DB but what i actually need is a way to relate my tables for my entity, i have a DB with this 2 tables

```
dbo.Fleets 
OwnerId   (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null) 
ownerName (nvarchar(255),not null)


dbo.UserAccount
UserID        (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
UserName      (nchar(20), null)
SelectedFleet (FK,uniqueidentifier,null)
PrimaryFleet  (FK,UniqueIdentifier,null)
```

The foreign keys are for `Fleets.OwnerId`, both of them, so inside my application i want to be able to get the fleet for my Primary and `SelectedFleet` with `EF`.

so if i run `var v = dc.UserAccounts.Where(a => a.UserName == model.UserName).Include(d => d.Fleet).SingleOrDefault();` I'll be getting my complete results

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5559300/1453651), it may help.

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer to use DataAnnotations.

```
    [Table("UserAccounts")]
    public class UserAccounts
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Fleets> Fleets { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Fleets")]
    public class Fleets
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual UserAccounts UserAccount { get; set; }
    }
```

Then to access the users fleet you would use

```
var v = dc.UserAccounts.Where(a => a.UserName == model.UserName).Include(d => d.Fleet).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: But how does that solve my problem? I need 2 different fleets per account

Comment: So if a UserAccount needs to have many Fleets then this is not a One - One relationship. It becomes a One - Many. I have edited the code to represent that.

Comment: Actually its 2 x one to one

Comment: @pato.llaguno - From what I understand you have 2 classes, a parent(UserAccounts) and a child(Fleets). From that you want to be able to access the child property after you have successfully located the correct parent based on Id. Is that right?