# Entity Framework "Multiple object sets per type are not supported. "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a parent child relationship Model of the same object type.
Exactly like the one over here:

[Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table)

I tried all the things mentioned but migrations always gives me the error above.

Here are my models:
Main Entity:

```
public class L_Colaborador
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<L_ColaboradorPais> L_ColaboradorPais { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<L_ColaboradorPais> L_ColaboradorFilhos { get; set; }
}
```

RelationShip Entity with Parent/ Child foreign keys:

```
public class L_ColaboradorPais
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PaiId { get; set; }
    public int FilhoId { get; set; }


    public virtual L_Colaborador Pai { get; set; }
    public virtual L_Colaborador Filho { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my DBContext:

```
public DbSet<L_Colaborador> L_Colaboradores { get; set; }
public DbSet<L_Colaborador> L_ColaboradorPais { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{


   modelBuilder.Ignore<V_HorasSum>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<L_ColaboradorPais>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.Pai)
            .WithMany(t => t.L_ColaboradorFilhos)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.PaiId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<L_ColaboradorPais>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.Filho)
                .WithMany(t => t.L_ColaboradorPais)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.FilhoId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Can't really figure out why am I getting this error:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'L_Colaboradores' and 'L_ColaboradorPais' can both contain instances of type 'TimeProject.Models.L_Colaborador'.

And I have also tried using ForeignKey annotation

Comment: Did you Google your error message?

Comment: You mention `L_Colaboradores` but nowhere in your code can we see that.

Comment: @Crowcoder I did a lot actually i tried all first 5 pages of google...

Comment: @CodingYoshi I edited my code on bd context thanks for pointing me out

Comment: That can't be all of your DbSets. Where is type `PM` defined?

Comment: The exception is telling you that your `DbContext` contains property `public DbSet<L_Colaborador> L_ColaboradorPais { get; set; }`. The type of the property should be changed to `DbSet<L_ColaboradorPais>`.

Comment: @Crowcoder Sorry PM was a typing mistake

Comment: Do you see how you have two DbSets of the same type? You can only have one even if you name them differently.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thats excatly the problem thank you very much! If you add as an answer i will gladdly accept thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling EF to create the model object `L_Colaborador` twice in your DBContext.  I think what you mean to do is this:

```
public DbSet<L_Colaborador> L_Colaboradores { get; set; }
public DbSet<L_ColaboradorPais> L_ColaboradorPais { get; set; }
```