# EF Core 2.2 - Two foreign keys to same table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

I have a similar problem to the one posted here:
[Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table), however it's very old and doesn't apply to Core and I can't get the suggestions to work for me.

Basically, I'm trying to create a fixture table which will have two foreign keys to the team table. A fixture is made up of a home team and an away team. Having nullable fields isn't an option.

Consider a fixture, with two teams.

```
public class Fixture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}



public class Team
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fixture> HomeFixtures { get; set; } = new List<Fixture>();
    public ICollection<Fixture> AwayFixtures { get; set; } = new List<Fixture>();
}
```

I get the error...

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Fixture.HomeTeam' of type 'Team'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

So I tried to add some OnModelCreating code in the database context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
                    .HasOne(m => m.HomeTeam)
                    .WithMany(t => t.HomeFixtures)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
                    .HasOne(m => m.AwayTeam)
                    .WithMany(t => t.AwayFixtures)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.AwayTeamId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
```

Then I got the error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Fixtures_Teams_HomeTeamId' on table 'Fixtures' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Can anyone help with getting this setup please?

Thanks.

Comment: The navigation properties in the show `Fixture` class are duplicated (probably a typo). Other than that, the model + shown fluent configuration should produce what you need. Make sure to regenerate the migration, "cycles or multiple cascade paths" error is when you *don't* use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`, so I guess you are running stale migration.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks - it was an stale migration indeed. i deleted the migrations, generated a fresh one and after update-database it all worked as i expected. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Fixture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeamId")]
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AwayTeamId")]
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

This way navigation will work. Also as suggested by @Ivan remove duplicate getters and setters.

Comment: This is still a viable answer for EF Core 3.1, saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Solution below worked for me for EF Core 3:

1. Make sure to make foreign keys nullable
2. Specify default behavior on Delete

   ```
   public class Match 
   { 
      public int? HomeTeamId { get; set; }
      public int? GuestTeamId { get; set; }

      public float HomePoints { get; set; }
      public float GuestPoints { get; set; }
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }

      public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
      public Team GuestTeam { get; set; }
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                   .HasRequired(m => m.HomeTeam)
                   .WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                   .HasRequired(m => m.GuestTeam)
                   .WithMany(t => t.AwayMatches)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.GuestTeamId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
   }
   ```