# Entity Framework - Main table with two users with different name field, relation with a single field of foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using a EF with .Net Core 2.2. And I cannot figurated out how to solve the following problem:

I have the PQL and PM fields, these fields are the key of a user (Based in the table User).
So, How I can create two relations of two fields to the same field (In the secondary table) using EF...

Example, a requirement is to create a query to get all projects per user, where the user be the PM or the PQL...

The main table is:

```
public class ProjectHeader
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdProjectHeader { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FK_IdUser")]
        [Column("IdUser")]
        public int PM { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FK_IdUser")]
        [Column("IdUser")]
        public int PQL { get; set; }

        // NOT LINK WITH USER TABLE CORRECTLY
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

The User table is:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem... on main table I included:

```
[ForeignKey("PM")]
public User PmUser { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PQL")]
public User PqlUser { get; set; }
```

...using the User Entity for both fields (Using a Foreign Key - Equal to the field on the main table)...
so, the PM match with idUser... and PQL match with idUser

Now... I have a circular reference when I tried to update the database using Code-first...

So, in the class `public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext` I override the foreign keys:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectHeader>().HasOne(m => m.PmUser).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectHeader>().HasOne(m => m.PqlUser).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[A link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table?rq=1) to a question similar to this one. I would suggest you to research and use Entity Framework's Fluent API. Basically in your context class (that inherits DbContext class) you override the OnModelCreating method like so:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts);
    }
}
```

Inside you can configure some advanced relations for your database. You can look it up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: I will check it out. I'm checking the way to do it directly on the entities (If it's possible)... otherwise, I will create a Context to manipulate those cases. Thanks for your contribution!