# Configuring cascade delete throws error - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I have the following entities:

```
public class CompanyRelationshipEntity
{
    public int ParentCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ChildCompanyId { get; set; }
    public CompanyEntity? ParentCompany { get; set; }
    public CompanyEntity? ChildCompany { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class CompanyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CompanyRelationshipEntity? ChildCompany{ get; set; }
    public CompanyRelationshipEntity? ParentCompany { get; set; }
}
```

With the following relationship defined on the CompanyRelationshipTable:

```
        model.ToTable("CompanyRelationship");
        model.HasKey(x => new { x.ParentCompanyId, x.ChildCompanyId });

        model.HasOne(e => e.ChildCompany)
            .WithOne(e => e.ChildCompany)
            .HasForeignKey<CompanyRelationshipEntity>(x => x.ChildCompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        model.HasOne(e => e.ParentCompany)
            .WithOne(e => e.ParentCompany)
            .HasForeignKey<CompanyRelationshipEntity>(x => x.ParentCompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When trying to create the database I get the following:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_CompanyRelationship_Company_ParentCompanyId' on table 'CompanyRelationship' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints**

If I change this relationship to ClientCascade, it works.  The expected behaviour I want to achieve is to remove the record from the CompanyRelationship table if either the Parent or Child company is deleted but ideally I don't want to have to load this relationship before doing so.

Comment: This may help: [Ef 6 How To Set Two Foreign Keys To Same Table](https://www.faqcode4u.com/faq/526598/ef-6-how-to-set-two-foreign-keys-to-same-table)

Comment: [Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table) and [Entity Framework Core - Configure Two Foreign Keys to the Same Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2uDU47uezY)

Comment: Here you can find another detailed answer too [Defining multiple Foreign Key for the Same table in Entity Framework Code First](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/28570916/defining-multiple-foreign-key-for-the-same-table-in-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: None of these achieve the behavior I want.