# Entity Framework Code First in Serverside Blazor: Problem with two relations between the same tables

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, ef-core-6.0

I'm working on a serverside blazor project (.net 6) using Entity Framework with code first. I have two tables, let's say (in order to protect private data), we have the Tables *Band* and *Bandsman*. Originally, every band could have exactly one bandsman, a bandsman could be connected to more then one band though. It's an example, so please don't question this assumptive circumstances.

I created two classes:

```
[Table("Band")]
public partial class Band
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public int? BandsmanId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bandsman Bandsman { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bandsman")]
public partial class Bandsman
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Band> Band { get; set; }
}
```

So far everything works fine. Entity Framework set the correct foreign key. But now I have to insert a second bandsman. Let's say, the first bandsman is a keyboarder, now I need a drummer as well. So I altered the existing classes:

```
[Table("Band")]
public partial class Band
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public int? BandsmanId { get; set; }
    public int? DrummerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bandsman Bandsman { get; set; }
    public virtual Bandsman Drummer { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bandsman")]
public partial class Bandsman
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Band> Band { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Band> Drummer { get; set; }
}
```

I know I have to tell Entity Framework now how to map the tables. So I added mapping instructions to the *OnModelCreating*-Method in DbContext:

```
builder.Entity<Band>().HasOne(a => a.Bandsman).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.BandsmanId);
builder.Entity<Band>().HasOne(a => a.Drummer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.DrummerId);
```

This doesn't work. When I create the migrations I see that Entity Frameworks tries to create new Columns *BandsmanId1* and *BandsmanId2* to the *Band*-Table instead of using the Columns I defined.

So I tried to add the instructions the other way around, too, in addition to the previous ones:

```
builder.Entity<Bandsman>().HasMany<Band>(a => a.Band).WithOne().HasForeignKey(b => b.BandsmanId);
builder.Entity<Bandsman>().HasMany<Band>(a => a.Drummer).WithOne().HasForeignKey(b => b.DrummerId);
```

It's still the same, Entity Framework tries to add new columns and map the foreign keys to them.

I also tried to rename *Band.BandsmanId* to *Band.KeyboarderId* or rather add and map a new column with the new name (so existing data won't get lost), rename *Band.Bandsman* to *Band.Keyboarder* and *Bandsman.Band* to *Bandsman.Keyboarder*. With no effect, Entity Framework still seems incapable to use the colums I want it to use. I guess the instructions I added to *OnModelCreating* in DbContext are incorrect, but I'm not able to find out how to put it right. I found some examples here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I can't manage to convert one of this examples to my code.
So I hope someone can help me to put the classes and instructions right.

Comment: You misunderstand what the term ["relation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)) means in database theory. It _does not_ refer to a foreign-key constraint.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I edited this part of the question. It was a translation error, as English isn't my mother tongue. "Relation" is a correct translation for the word I would use in German most of the time, this question is one of the rare occasions where it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

After posting my question, I found the solution in a post that was shown as possibly related:
[Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table?rq=1)
I was close, my only mistake was not to name the virtual List-Property of the *Bandsman*-Class in the *.HasMany()*-Part of the instructions. So Entity Framework didn't now these properties were related to the foreign key columns in the *band*-table and tried to create the assumed-to-be-missing columns on its own. This way it works:

```
builder.Entity<Band>().HasOne(a => a.Bandsman).WithMany(b => b.Band).HasForeignKey(a => a.BandsmanId);
builder.Entity<Band>().HasOne(a => a.Drummer).WithMany(b => b.Drummer).HasForeignKey(a => a.DrummerId);
```