# Two fk's to same table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have an old desktop system, and I'm refactoring with backend with C# using EF Core.

In the old database, there is a table to define a complement product. I have two columns, and it's using the same origin table.

Main table: `Product`

```
Id
Name
etc...
```

Second table: `Complements`

```
Id - (Original product) FK -\> Product.Id
Id2 - (Complement product) FK -\> Product.Id
```

Can I construct this with EF Core?

My product code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Phoenix.Models.Products
{
    [Table("products")]
    [Comment("Cadastro de produtos")]
    [Index(nameof(Name), Name = "idx_prd_name", IsUnique = true)]
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("prd_id")]
        [Comment("Identificador unico")]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Column("prd_name")]
        [Comment("Nome do produto")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome do produto")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "É necessário pelo menos {1} caracteres!")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} suporta apenas {1} caracteres!")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `Complement` code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Phoenix.Models.Products
{
    [Table("complements")]
    [Comment("Cadastro de produtos complementares")]
    public class Complement
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("pcp_id")]
        [Comment("Identificador unico")]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Column("prc_id")]
        [Comment("Identificador do produto complementar")]
        [Display(Name = "Produto complementar")]
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
        [Display(Name = "Produto complementar")]
        public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }
    
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Column("prd_id")]
        [Comment("Identificador do produto principal")]
        [Display(Name = "Produto")]
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int OriginalId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I am trying the controller, VS generate a error message:

[image]

I intend to create a new table with two FK's to the same table.

Comment: I believe you have to use Fluent API instead of Data annotations.  Check out this post-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table

Answer (score 1):

While both FKs point to the Product table, they don't always reference the same Product row, so If you essentially have an Original Product ID and a Compliment Product Id, I would look to structure the Complements like:

```
[Table("complements")]
[Comment("Cadastro de produtos complementares")]
public class Complement
{
    [Key]
    [Column("pcp_id")]
    [Comment("Identificador unico")]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [Column("prc_id")]
    [Comment("Identificador do produto complementar")]
    [Display(Name = "Produto complementar")]
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Produto complementar")]
    public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [Column("prd_id")]
    [Comment("Identificador do produto principal")]
    [Display(Name = "Produto")]
    [ForeignKey("OriginalProduct")]
    public int OriginalId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product? OriginalProduct { get; set; }

}
```

ProductId is the FK to the "Product" navigation property while OriginalId is the FK to the "OriginalProduct" navigation property.